# Why use await in a certain scenario

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

If I have a GET request that simply returns something from the DB, should I do something like this:

```cs
return _dbContext.MyTable.Where(...).ToList();
```

or:

```cs
return await _dbContext.MyTable.Where(...).ToListAsync();
```

Aren't these 2 identical? This is what I think when I have an async version of a method: if I need to do something else in the meantime, I should use the async version. If not, go for the synchronous option. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The latter releases the thread whilst the async work (database query) is awaited. This can increase the throughput of the app; more threads available to service HTTP requests.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Basically, I should use await whenever possible in a web app?

Comment: See the duplicate question. There are some good answers in there.

Comment: For anyone interested, here's a summary of what I've read so far:
async/await on front-end: you get responsive UI. In web API: you get scalability.
Async/await in ASP .NET: use them when you have I/O operations - reading/writing files, queries, API calls (this is due to the thread being released).
Don't use them in CPU-bound tasks.

Comment: The main point is that `async/await` is all about **freeing up threads**. as stated in one of the answers in the recommended post.

Answer (score 0):

ToList() is a synchronous operation. It means that the code will block until the operation is completed.ToListAsync() is an asynchronous operation. It allows your code to continue executing other tasks while waiting for the database operation to complete.
If your method is declared as async then its better to use ToListAsync(). Using await allows the calling thread to be released during the database operation, enabling better resource utilization.
Hope this helps.

Comment: "_It allows your code to continue executing other tasks while waiting for the database operation to complete._" ASP.Net is multithreaded anyway. The point is that using the async version increases thread availability.

Comment: I understand. Let's assume 100 requests are made simultaneously on my web app. The requests are simple database queries (like the one from above). If the requests use the async versions of LINQ-to-SQL, will I get a better performance compared to using the synchronous versions?

Comment: Let's assume 100 requests are made simultaneously on your web app, your database server is able to handle 2048 connections simultaneously, and your CPU have 8 logical cores. And also assume that a single query to DB always cost 1 sec of time.
Then, in great oversimplification, processing 100 requests will cost you about 12 sec in total when using synchronous `ToList()`, or about 1 sec in total when using asynchronous `ToListAsync()`.

Comment: It's really oversimplification, in practice it doesn't look like that. Web server can spawn a lot of threds to handle request simultaneously. Yet it's a big waste of resources if you have tons of threads that are only waiting.

Answer (score 0):

In general, for ASP.Net/Core Web API or MVC you should see better overall performance using async/await for your server-side processing.

> Most client-side implementations it is unavoidable so we won't even talk about that

Even when your code process might not specifically be doing anything else concurrently, the intention is to support multiple concurrent requests from other users or processes.

async/await in this context potentially adds minor overheads to the individual request but allows the entire http request pipeline to more efficiently service multiple requests with a minimum number of threads.